# tooltip catcher c#

Tags: c#, tooltip, diagnostics

I want to create an application which can copy the tool tip (the tool tips which are shown on the current desktop/window) if I press hot keys. So how can I track whether the current desktop having a tool tip.

Comment: Couldn't you just use Print Screen to grab a screenshot? Seems like an odd requirement.

Answer (score 1):

First, its not possible to use the Managed.Net API to access windows in other applications so you will have to do somthing a bit different.

I guess you could use the Win32 API to enumerate windows and find those of the class `Tooltip_Class32`. Then you'd have to read the text on them.

You can enum windows as described on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531828/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-belonging-to-a-particular-process-using-net/2531840#2531840) and on PInvoke.net [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html).

If you limit to just the `Tooltip_Class32` then you will only get the tool tip windows.

I'm not sure how windows contructs a tool tip. I'm guessing you can read the text from the tool tip or from some child control window by using the `SendMessage` API with the `WM_GETTEXT` message like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18661/659190).

That should get you started, I've never actually done it myself but it seems feasible.