# winapi - a standard way to retrieve text from running text editor

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a standard *message* that can be sent to a text editor window or a certain *WinApi* call, that will retrieve the contents of the currently edited text?

For example, to retrieve the current contents of a *Notepad* window. (assumed that the most up to date text wasn't yet written to a file)

I've tried retrieving the text via `SendMessage` using `WM_GETTEXT`, `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` but I was able to retrieve the title text only.

Comment: Use `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` to know how many characters are in the editor, then allocate a buffer of that size and use `WM_GETTEXT` or `GetWindowText()` to fill it with editor's actual text. If you just want the selected text, use `EM_GETSEL`/`EM_EXGETSEL` afterwards to determine the start/end indexes of the range of selected characters within that text, and then copy those characters out to another buffer.

Comment: Typically you enumerate all processes IDs, check that the process has the required name, e.g. "notepad.exe". Then enumerate all threads for this process. Then use ```EnumThreadWindows``` API to get windows handles. Then check the window type/class - you only need text editboxes. Lastly you may use ```char text[256];
LRESULT result = SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(text), LPARAM(text));```

Comment: `WM_GETTEXT` will work reliably on some programs, but more generally you want to use the Accessibility APIs that "screen reader" software uses

Comment: *"Is there a standard message"* - In general, no. *"\[...\] or a certain WinApi call"* - Yes, [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11042272/103167

Comment: For an arbitrary text editor, no. The closest you will get is UI Automation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general **no** there is no standard message for this.

But Windows' **Notepad** has an "Edit" child which responds to `WM_GETTEXT` and `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` - messages normally used to retrieve text from input controls.

Here's a PoC demonstrating the idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL CALLBACK enumProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM) {
    std::vector<char> buf(100);
    GetClassNameA(hwnd, buf.data(), 100);
    if (strcmp(buf.data(), "Notepad")) return TRUE;
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, "Edit", NULL);
    if (!hwnd) return TRUE;
    int textLength = SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0) + 1;
    if (textLength <= 0) return TRUE;
    buf.resize(textLength);
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, textLength, (LPARAM)buf.data());
    std::cout << buf.data() << "\n";
    return TRUE;
}

int main() {
    EnumWindows(&enumProc, 0);
}
```

Works on Windows 10:

[image: retrieve text from running notepad winapi]

Comment: I've tried using WM_GETTEXT - isn't it returning just the window title?

Comment: You need to get the "Edit" child - see my code, it works.

Comment: Anything more advanced than Notepad isn't going to be using an edit control though so I wonder how useful this answer is really.

Comment: @JonathanPotter the first sentence in the answer states there's no standard way to retrieve the text, which is (unfortunately) a valid answer.

Comment: There is a standard way. It's UI Automation. But not every program supports that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're absolutely correct. By "standard way" I meant - a WinApi call / set of calls, because that was the context of my question. Excuse me for the ambiguity.